# Display image from an array and, when clicked, says the name of the image

Tags: c#, arrays, random, bitmap

[image]As a precursor: I am very new to C# and yes this is homework.

I am working on a program that stores 52 card .bmp's in an array, randomizes which cards appear in the 5 picture boxes, and then when the user clicks on the card, it displays the name of the card. I'm stuck on the last part of this. Thanks in advance!

```
 public partial class cardIdentifier : Form
{
    public cardIdentifier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
        pictureBox2.Image = deck[new Random(+1).Next(0, deck.Length)];
        pictureBox3.Image = deck[new Random(+5).Next(0, deck.Length)];
        pictureBox4.Image = deck[new Random(+10).Next(0, deck.Length)];
        pictureBox5.Image = deck[new Random(-7).Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }
    //Creating and adding images to the array
    Image[] deck = new Image[52] { Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubAce, Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubTwo, Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubThree, Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubFour, Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubFive , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubSix , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubSeven , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubEight , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubNine , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubTen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubJack , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubQueen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubKing , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeAce , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeTwo , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeThree , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeFour , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeFive , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeSix , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeSeven , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeEight , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeNine , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeTen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeJack , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeQueen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.spadeKing , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartAce , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartTwo , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartThree , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartFour , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartFive , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartSix , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartSeven , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartEight , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartNine , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartTen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartJack , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartQueen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.heartKing , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondAce , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondTwo , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondThree , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondFour , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondFive , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondSix , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondSeven , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondEight , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondNine , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondTen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondJack , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondQueen , Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.diamondKing  };

//Changes the card shown in picture box
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox3.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox4.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox5.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];
    }


    public void pictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK, NEED TO DISPLAY NAME OF CARD WHEN ITS CLICKED!
    }
}
```

}

Comment: added form picture.

Comment: Instead of using a class, which is the most extensible solution, you can use a dictionary to pair a string with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another class like this:

```
public class Card
{
    public Image CardImage {get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Create an array of those classes instead of `Image` array like this. This will help you keep a card's image and it's name in a single instance so you can get it later on:

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52] { new Card { CardImage = Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubAce, Name = "ClubAce" }, // ... the rest of your cards };
```

When you create your picturebox, set the `Tag` property to the name of the card like this:

```
var card5 = deck[new Random(-7).Next(0, deck.Length)];
pictureBox5.Image = card5.CardImage;
pictureBox5.Tag = card5; // Later on you will read this to get the name
```

And change the click method like this:

```
public void pictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK, NEED TO DISPLAY NAME OF CARD WHEN ITS CLICKED!
    var cardName = ((sender as PictureBox).Tag as Card).Name
}
```

Comment: I understand this solution, but it appears the statements i have for creating random cards break when using this solution. I know it has to do with how the array is built, but I don't understand how to fix it.

`code  pictureBox1.Image = deck[new Random().Next(0, deck.Length)];`

I get " Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Card_Identify.cardIdentifier.Card' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: No that is not how I have it in my answer. Remember now your array has `Card` types so for each picturebox you need to do it the way I have in my answer: 1. Get the card at random: `var card5 = deck[new Random(-7).Next(0, deck.Length)];` 2. Assign the image from the card: `pictureBox5.Image = card5.CardImage;` 3. Asign the tag: `pictureBox5.Tag = card5; // Later on you will read this to get the name` You need to do it like that for all the pictureboxes but obviously changing the random number etc.

Comment: I want to seriously thank you for the help so far. I fixed the random cards ( I think) but i'm getting errors when I try to add more cards to the array `code Card[] deck = new Card[] { new Card { CardImage = Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubAce, Name = "Ace of Clubs" },  { CardImage = Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubTwo, Name = "Two of Clubs" } };`

I get the errors "CS0623 Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead."

Comment: You have to keep putting the `new` keyword for every `Card` you create. You are forgetting it. Do it like this:`Card[] deck = new Card[] { new Card { CardImage = Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubAce, Name = "Ace of Clubs" }, new Card { CardImage = Card_Identify.Properties.Resources.clubTwo, Name = "Two of Clubs" } };` See how after the comma, there is a `new` again. So if you are creating 52 cards, you will have 52 news.

Comment: You are the best, Thank you so much, fully working program now.

Answer (score 0):

**Nowhere in your code I see a relationship bitmap/card name.**

You could do the following, a small class to define a card:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Card[] _cards;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // build your array of cards
            Card[] cards =
            {
                new Card
                {
                    Path = "ace_heart.png",
                    Name = "Ace Of Hearts"
                }
                // etc ...
            };

            // load their bitmaps
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                card.Bitmap = new Bitmap(card.Path);
            }

            // keep a reference
            _cards = cards;
        }

        private int GetRandomCardIndex(int seed)
        {
            var random = new Random(seed);
            var next = random.Next(52);
            return next;
        }

        private void Demo()
        {
            var cardIndex = GetRandomCardIndex(1234);
            var card = _cards[cardIndex];
            var cardName = card.Name; // there you are
            var cardBitmap = card.Bitmap;
        }
    }

    internal class Card
    {
        public Bitmap Bitmap;
        public string Name;
        public string Path;
    }
}
```

I see that your cards have been in put in `Resources`, in my example these are local files. Ultimately it is possible to fetch card name from `Resources` but it's probably outside the scope of your homework.

**To deploy a card image in your project:**

- drop bitmaps in your project
- select them all and go to *Properties* window

  - `Build action` = `Content`
  - `Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy if newer`
- or simply copy all the bitmaps next to your EXE (in bin\Debug subdir)

[image]

Comment: Is this building an additional class (seperate) or is it inline with the rest of the code? I'm sorry, again, newer to C# and OOP

Comment: Yes, and this helper class is below the Form class (I didn't bother moving it to its own file). There are 100s of ways to achieve what you need, I just took what I think was the simplest approach.

Comment: Why would @JacobZayak do it this way? He already has the images in a resource file, which is actually better than this approach. He just needs a mapping from card image to the card name...